# constructor with return generic type based on param enum: TS2322

Tags: typescript, generics

I'm coding type checked constructor function.
I want return object type to have exactly same field value as param value but another fields depending on that value.

```
function testConstructor<T extends En>(
  val: T
): {
  field: T;
  [x: string]: any;
} {
  switch (val) {
    case En.one:
      return {
        field: En.one,
        anotherField: 1,
      };
    case En.two:
      return {
        field: En.two,
        someAnotherField: 2,
      };
    default:
      return {
        field: val,
      };
  }
}
```

I'm getting an error:

```
TS2322: Type 'En.two' is not assignable to type 'T'. 'En.two' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'En'.
```

Why am I keep getting this error and how can I fix it?
Why switch guard isn't working?

---

Errors after @Phu-Ngo solution (this version of code closer to my actual code.)

```
enum Enum {
  one = 'one',
  two = 'two',
}

type Type1 = {
  field: typeof Enum.one;
  anotherField: number;
};

type Type2 = {
  field: typeof Enum.two;
  someAnotherField: number;
};

function testConstructor<T extends Enum>(
  val: T
): {
  field: T;
  [x: string]: any;
} {
  switch (val) {
    case Enum.one:
      let obj1: Type1 = {
        field: val,
        anotherField: 1,
      };
      return obj1;
    case Enum.two:
      let obj2: Type2 = {
        field: val,
        someAnotherField: 1,
      }
      return obj2;
  }
  throw Error(`unknown value ${val}`);
}
```

Errors:

1. At the line `field: val`:

```
TS2322: Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'Enum.one'.   Type 'Enum' is not assignable to type 'Enum.one'.
```

2. At the line `return obj1`:

```
TS2322: Type 'Type1' is not assignable to type '{ [x: string]: any; field: T; }'.   Types of property 'field' are incompatible.     Type 'Enum.one' is not assignable to type 'T'.       'Enum.one' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'Enum'.
```

Comment: your type guard restricts `val` to be `En.one` all right, but the `field` field of the return value is still required to be `T`. `T` and `En.one` are different subtypes of `En`, thus the error. Use `val` instead of `En.one`.

Comment: @Phu-Ngo, `> Use val instead of En.one` — right, it works, thanks! :) Is there another solution, without modifying the body of function, maybe to declare parameter and return type differently?

Comment: @Phu-Ngo, I completed code in my question closer to my actual code and I'm getting another errors :(

Comment: Eh, this is going to be an instance where you just use [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) and move on, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wQAQYw).  I doubt you'll find anything where the compiler can verify the safety of what you're trying to do without significant refactoring.  If this meets your needs I can write up an answer for why you need to do this.  Let me know.

Comment: @jcalz, thanks! `> what you're trying to do without significant refactoring`. Can you write minimal working code example?

Comment: Assuming you need to keep explicit `Type1` and `Type2` references, I'd say something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/N7bDGw).  The issue is that you can't ever get the compiler to narrow the *type parameter* `T` via control flow analysis (like `switch`/`case`), so you should not try to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved not with one constructor function but with [mapped](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) constructors functions and [Extract](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#predefined-conditional-types).

```
enum Enum {
  one = 'one',
  two = 'two',
}

type Type1 = {
  field: typeof Enum.one;
  anotherField: number;
};

type Type2 = {
  field: typeof Enum.two;
  someAnotherField: number;
};

type TypeN = Type1 | Type2;

type ConstructorN<T> = () => Extract<
  TypeN,
  {
    field: T;
  }
>;

type Constructors = {
  [T in Enum]: ConstructorN<T>;
};

let constructors: Constructors = {
  [Enum.one]: () => {
    let obj: Type1 = {
      field: Enum.one,
      anotherField: 1,
    };
    return obj;
  },
  [Enum.two]: () => {
    let obj: Type2 = {
      field: Enum.two,
      someAnotherField: 2,
    };
    return obj;
  },
};

console.log(constructors[Enum.one]())
console.log(constructors[Enum.two]())
```